# Restart or Clear App Farbic Cache using CCNET

Tags: asp.net, caching, cruisecontrol.net

I'm using CCNet as a CI server I want it to restart cache or clear it (App Fabric) with every build.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not familiar with App Fabric.

I've done some looking and found the following information on [using Powershell to administer AppFabric's Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718177%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).

Using the information there, you can use the [Powershell task](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/PowerShell_Task) to accomplish what you need.